# What Bayesian model should I use for posterior room identification?

Tags: bayesian, markov-process, markov-chain

I have n rooms (which can be considered as states) and a sensor on my robot which gives me a probability array of what room it is in (this array is of size n and its sum is 1).
At every timestamp (the timestamps are regularly spaced, say 5 seconds) the robot takes a measurement and stores it.

Moreover, I know my robot is quite slow and the rooms are quite large, so the robot should stay in the same room during x timestamps (for example with x = 12, it should stay in the same room for 60 seconds).

Now here is the tricky part:

- the sensor is rather noisy so the right room should be in the worst case at the third place in the sensor array (if you order by decreasing probability)
- fortunately, I only need to know about the rooms where the robot was **after** he has finished travelling (hence the "posterior room identification"), meaning that the robot does not take advantage of this sensor when it travels
- there is no prior on room topology, you could consider that the rooms are all connected to each other.

One last piece of information: I can train the model with a groundtruth dataset.

I don't think there needs to be more data added to design a model. I was planning to go for a simple Markov state model but the three observations I made make me doubt it would apply correctly, since the present depends on the past **and** on the future.

What model would you use?

Comment: Just a comment- The present is only dependent on the the future once the future is observed. This is a property of a first-order markov process.

Comment: That is why I am looking for a posterior model which knows of the past, present, and future :) (the dataset is no longer updated)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a first-order hidden Markov model.  The transition distribution of the model corresponds to the room topology, as well as the probability of lingering in the same room.  I would learn that from the training data.  Given a prior on the initial state and the sensor readings at each time step, I would use a forward-backward algorithm to estimate the posterior probability of being in each room at each time step.